# Does this equation have a real root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$2x + 10 = 15x - 33$

Does this equation have a real root?

Please show your work when possible.
Thanks!

Comment: Subtract $2x$ on both sides. We get $10=13x-33$. Then add $33$ on both sides. We get $43=13x$. Now multiply both sides by $1/13$. We get $43/13=x$.

Comment: Thanks! Now in order to prove that x = 43/13 satisfies the equation, how would I show my work? I put x = 43/13 into the equation but some how it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean does this equation have a solution?
$$
\begin{align}
2x+10&=15x-33\\
10&=13x-33\\
43&=13x\\
\frac{43}{13}&=x
\end{align}
$$
So the equation above holds only when $x=43/13$.

**EDIT.** You asked to verify that it indeed is a solution. To do that, we just check that the solution works.
$$
2x+10=2(43/13)+10=86/13+10=216/13
$$
and
$$
15x-33=15(43/13)-33=645/13-33=216/33
$$
Since these are both equal, our solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I got that far, but I now need to know if x = 43/12 satisfies the equation. I know that it does, but how would I figure that out?

Comment: Compute $2\times \frac{43}{13}+10$ and $15\times\frac{43}{13}-33$ and check they are equal.

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I can't believe you actually answered this question.

Comment: @IgorRivin Why wouldn't someone answer this question? The most simple questions are the most important to answer. They are the ones that allow asking and answering more complicated questions. There was a time in which all of us didn't know the answer to this question, and we were all told the answer. Why not do the same with the next person?

Comment: @ABC because, in my humble opinion, doing someone's arithmetic for him does not actually teach anything.

Comment: @IgorRivin What else would you do? On this site you are limited, with arithmetic at this level, especially if the OP does not provide all their steps, there is little to do. There is only 2 steps in acquiring the solution. So there is little other way to answer questions such as these. Sometimes, it's important that they see how things are done. Seeing is also an important part of learning-not as much as doing-but it is still a part of the process.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life this is precisely why I would not answer this question. The only way to learn things at this basic technical level is practice. I am sure the person's teachers have tried, and the phrasing of the question -- "does it have a real solution" -- makes it reasonably clear that the OP is not a second grader (which is where this sort of thing is usually studied).